# Change color of bullets in a list

Tags: css, list

Is there a modern CSS solution to change the color of the bullets?

It should work for all types of bullets.

**Disc Style**

---

[image]

**Decimal Style**

---

[image]

**etc.**

My list looks like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

I can't change this markup.

Please don't give solutions like this:

```
<ul>
     <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></li>
     <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></li>
</ul>

li {
  color: red; /* bullet color */
}
li span {
  color: black; /* text color */
}
```

**This requires a markup change**

or

```
li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red; 
}
```

**This works only for one list style type**

Comment: What's wrong with using the type of solution you propose in your last example? After all, numbered lists and bulleted lists are different beasts - the elements of one are wrapped with a `<ul>` and those of the other are wrapped with a `<ol>`. The css-only solution is trivial if you're prepared to have different rules for both `ul` elements and `ol` elements.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I forgot to add. For the decimal enumeration I have the <ol><li>... markup. But for <ul><li>... there are different list style types.

Comment: Sure,so how do you differentiate between the different desired output of different `ul` lists?

Comment: They have all different classes.

Comment: so then presumably, they all already have css rules that target them. I'd just throw the pertinent attributes into these rules and be done with it. I see you've accepted an answer, so I guess you've got a satisfactory solution. In any case, I've just discovered a couple of attribute of a `li`'s rule I'd not been aware of before, cheers. :) Here's the two I'd use for an `ol` and its items - `ol { counter-reset: item }` and `ol li:before{ content: counter(item) ". ";  counter-increment: item; color: red;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS3 specs define a [`::marker`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudo-element) pseudo-element to do exactly what you want. But, as of today, no browser supports this option.

Firefox has a very similar element, but of course this is browser-specific:

```
li::-moz-list-bullet {
  color: red;
}
```

So practically: No, there is no such solution for your problem right now. Usually, you will either use a `span` or a `:before` as you suggested yourself, already.

**Edit:** For numbered lists, you could even do:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    li:before {
      content: counter(counter) ". ";
      color: red;
    }
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      counter-increment: counter;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

**Edit 2:** Solution with `attr(data-bullet)`:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    ul.custom {
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul.custom li:before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: attr(data-bullet);
      color: red;
      width: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="custom">
  <li data-bullet="a">Item 1</li>
  <li data-bullet="b">Item 2</li>
  <li data-bullet="ba">Item 3.1<br/>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: I thought I once saw a solution with `data attr` or something.

Comment: Sure, you can set the ``content`` using ``attr(data-bullet)`` also, but this will require a markup change, too. And basically, it's the same solution as proposed above already.

Comment: Added another example for ``attr(data-bullet)`` to my initial answer.